# How to mock a window.location function in Karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I would like to mock a functionality in Karma who returns a file after clicking a download button.
I have the following AngularJS controller:

```
var secure = angular.module('secure', []);
secure.controller('ProcedureController', ProcedureController);
ProcedureController.$inject = ['$controller', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http'];

function ProcedureController($controller, $rootScope, $scope, $http) {

  ... // Controller does more stuff

  var href = window.location.href.split('/');
  var baseUrl = href[0] + '//' + href[2];
  var url = baseUrl + "/secure/regulations";

  $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.questions = data[0];
    })

  $scope.download = function (msg) {
    window.location = url + "/" + msg + "/attachment";
  }
}
```

The window.location object just call a RESTful service who provides him the desired file directly.
And this is, basically, my try-test:

```
describe('ProcedureController', function () {
  beforeEach(module('secure'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $http, $controller, $injector) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ProcedureController = $controller('ProcedureController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $http: $http
    });
  }));

  it ('should download something', function() {
    expect(scope.download(1)).toBeDefined();
  });

 });
```

So, my idea is to check when *scope.download* function is called, if it returns the right url, namely, when I try *scope.download(1)*, the expected answer would be **/secure/regulations/1/attachment**, roughly.

How should I mock it? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `$window` or `$location`? These could be injected and you can mock them using `inject()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: Yep, you're right. I just didn't realise. Now I'm using that reference. Thx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) instead:

```
var secure = angular.module('secure', []);
secure.controller('ProcedureController', ProcedureController);
ProcedureController.$inject = ['$controller', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$window'];

function ProcedureController($controller, $rootScope, $scope, $http, $window) {

  ... // Controller does more stuff

  var href = $window.location.href.split('/');
  var baseUrl = href[0] + '//' + href[2];
  var url = baseUrl + "/secure/regulations";

  $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.questions = data[0];
    })

  $scope.download = function (msg) {
    $window.location = url + "/" + msg + "/attachment";
  }
}

describe('ProcedureController', function () {
  var windowObj = {location: {href: ''}};

  beforeEach(mock.module(function($provide) {
     $provide.value('$window', windowObj);
  }));
  beforeEach(module('secure'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $http, $controller, $injector) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ProcedureController = $controller('ProcedureController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $http: $http
    });
  }));

  it ('should download something', function() {
    expect(scope.download).toBeDefined();
    scope.download(1);
    expect(windowObj.location.href).toEqual('/secure/regulations/1/attachment');
  });

 });
```

Comment: Very grateful! Just a little feedback: First, a trifle, I had to add `angular.mock` to run it. But, the main problem was that mock function always returned an `undefined` in href property (even it was different from empty). So, I had to get only `windowObj.location` instead. Of course, return value was different, but that's just a parse issue. Know why?

Comment: In your code you are assigning `$window.location = url + "/" + msg + "/attachment";` instead of `$window.location.href`, could it be that?

Comment: Yepp! Close enough! Just adding a fake host to `windowObj` works (and the expected response). Otherwise, you will have an _undefined_ host, but right pathname.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a number of variables here, but let's start with the test. First, you don't really need to "mock it" because you're running a Jasmine test through Karma who is loading some form of browser. I **hope** you're using `PhantomJS` instead of something like `Chrome`.

But, let's start out with `PhantomJS`. The code for your test should probably look something like this:

```
it ('should download something', function() {
  scope.download(1);
  expect(window.location).toBeDefined();
  expect(window.location).toBe('some static URL that it should be');
});
```

However, you need to fix up the initialization for your controller. You need to make sure you can meet the need of this line:

```
var href = window.location.href.split('/');
```

This means that when you build your controller here:

```
ProcedureController = $controller('ProcedureController', {
```

you're going to need to set the `window.location` to something **before executing `$controller`** so that it builds the `url` variable properly.

Now, if you're using `Chrome` then you're likely to see real movement in the browser. I don't think this will cause any problems but it's just not necessary. It's going to be best to use `PhantomJS` so that you can run those tests in the console.